# Java Can't Finding RFCOMM Output Port

Tags: java, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have a HC-05 Bluetooth board.  It is just a circuit board that connects to the Tx and Rx pins of a UART output of a microprocessor chip and transmits Bluetooth.  On a PC I use the WinXP Bluetooth Devices program to pair the PC to the HC-05.  Pairing creates two new comports, Outgoing (usually COM10) and Incoming (usually COM11) and if I use a program like Hyperterminal I can connect to the outgoing comport and receive the serial data being sent by the UART.

My problem is I can't get java to find that comport.  I have tried a number of java programs that search for comports.  None of them seem able to find the Outgoing port COM10.  They all can find COM11 and other comports.  But COM10 seems to be where the data I want is arriving.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, forget it.  I have been trying to solve this problem for three weeks.  No one seems able to help me.  Now my searches keep turning up my postings asking for help.

I will do the project in Visual Basic.   It could have been completed 2.5 weeks ago.

Sorry for using the space and bandwidth.